# Where are the log files of OverSIP (if there are any)?

Tags: ruby, logging, websocket, sip

I'm searching for the log files of OverSIP, but so far no luck, the google searches are note very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default oversip logs via syslog, with facility daemon.  SO take a look at your syslogd configuration and you should be able to see the files from there.  Probably /var/log/.